# I am trying to access videos of my youtube channel in flutter app using google youtube API. But it gives following error

Tags: flutter, youtube-api

noSuchMethodError: The getter 'snippet' was called on null. Reciever: null Tried calling snippet

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic).

Comment: Yes, please add an example.